# mass update mysql table decimal value and change column field type

Tags: mysql

Currently the `balance_amount` column in MySQL is using `double` type, and it contains values such as `11.28839999999999`.
I want to round such values to 2 decimal places to become 11.29, and I want to run a mass update to all the other 80 tables in the system so that it will show 2 decimal places only. After which, I want to change it from `double` to `decimal (10,2)` type.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `account` (
  `account_id` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance_amount` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

So how can I achieve it?

Comment: 80 tables? Crikey. Export your DDLs to a text file. Run find and replace on double default null, and then reimport. Keep a backup.

Comment: This does not work because the values will be truncated. Exporting to DDL and run the changes from there, I did that before. The value from 11.2883999999999 becomes 11.28

Comment: You said you wanted (10,2). What did you think would happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can round the corresponding columns in each table to 2 decimal places using:

```
Update <table-name> SET <column-name> = ROUND(<column-name>, 2);
```

Then alter the corresponding column in each table to be a `DECIMAL(10, 2)`:

```
ALTER TABLE `<table-name>` CHANGE COLUMN `<column-name>` `<column-name>` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL ;
```

But this is something you should be doing in your maintenance window, not live hours and you should backup your database as a disaster management measure before doing this.

Comment: The first step is redundant. And good luck repeating this 80 times :-(

Comment: @Strawberry redundant as in ?

Comment: @Strawberry I am not sure that is the case. Converting a column directly to `DECIMAL` rounds `10.99` to `11.00`. He would want to preserve 10.99 in his case, wouldn't he ?

Comment: Converting it to DECIMAL(5,2) would result in 10.99

Comment: @Strawberry But he wants the columns to be `(10,2)` type