# MYSQL - Update value in column "price" to 2 decimal places

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database with a column named `"price"` - within this column there are prices rounded to 5 decimal places, `e.g 62.083333` - I would like to run a command to change every value within `"price"` column to just 2 decimal places, `e.g 62.08`

Is there a simple command to run on this column? We have over 36,000,000 values so would prefer not to have to update them all manually! :)

Would this command be the one?

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,2),price)
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate

Comment: Column data types, old and new?

Comment: Data type = decimal(20,6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a similar question:  [mass update mysql table decimal value and change column field type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027805/mass-update-mysql-table-decimal-value-and-change-column-field-type)

You can use

```
ALTER TABLE '<name>' CHANGE COLUMN '<name>' DECIMAL(20,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try , 
>   UPDATE table_name SET price = round(price,2) where *your
>                                 conditions*;

Answer (score 0):

Simply alter table and modify data type

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName] MODIFY COLUMN [ColumnNameHere] decimal(20,2)
```